# How to functionally test an app that has a GUI and also CLI

Tags: testing, functional-testing, testcase

How should I functionally test an app from which you can execute its functionalities either through the GUI or through CLI? If I make changes to a functionality, lets say "Read a file"; should I include rainy/sunny day test cases for each execution mode (GUI/CLI) even when no changes were made to the interfaces (GUI nor CLI commands) and they both run the same code? Example of possible test cases:

1. Successfully Read file through GUI
2. Successfully read file through CLI
3. Attempt to read a corrupted file through GUI
4. Attempt to read a corrupted file through CLI
5. Attempt to read a non-existing file through GUI
6. Attempt to read a non-existing file through CLI

You get the pattern? Seems overkill to me when each of those would be executing the same code.

#testing #functionalTesting #testCases

I tried the given approach just to be sure I get better coverage of scenarios but still unsure if the test suite could be more efficient. Feel free to make any correction not even on-topic please.